# AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput use same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, video, multipeer-connectivity

I am using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` for Multipeer-Connectivity frames and `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` for video recording. But can't work at same time.

When i add `MovieFileOutput`

```
if ([self.CaptureSession canAddOutput:MovieFileOutput])
    [self.CaptureSession addOutput:MovieFileOutput];
```

Then not get AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput add

```
AVCaptureMultipeerVideoDataOutput *multipeerVideoOutput = [[AVCaptureMultipeerVideoDataOutput alloc] initWithDisplayName:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]];
multipeerVideoOutput.delegate = self;
[self.CaptureSession addOutput:multipeerVideoOutput];
```

Not get MovieFileOutput. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone have above solutions.!??

Comment: No one have solution.? i need help.Thanks

Comment: not supported by apple yet